# Sending PUT body request with nested json

Tags: java, rest-assured

Below is the body of my POST request: 
Request Body:

```
{
    "name": "testmodel",
    "id": 27,
    "versions": [{
        "number": 1,
        "attribute": "test"
    }]
}
```

I want to use  Hashmap to send the POST body request (code below) using RestAssured but but when I print this the body is not sent in the correct format

```
 Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("name","testmodel");
            map.put("id",27);
            map.put("versions", asList(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                put("number", "1");
                put("attribute", "test");
            }}));
System.out.println(map);
```

This is my Rest Assured DSL:

```
given().               
        contentType(ContentType.JSON).
        body(map).
when().
        post("http://someURL/something").
then().
        statusCode(200).
        log().everything();
```

BOdy which is getting printed:

```
{name=testmodel, versions=[{number=1, attribute=test}],  id=1790}
```

Expected Body:

```
{"name:"testmodel", "versions":[{"number":"1", "attribute":"test"}],  "id":27}
```

Can someone please tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: What is the code for your server? What is serving the JSON, Spring Boot? Jersey?

Comment: `{name=testmodel, versions=[{number=1, attribute=test}],  id=1790}` is the output of `map.toString()`. The logging method you're calling doesn't convert to JSON, it just calls `toString`

Comment: @Yserbius: Its Spring Boot.

Comment: Can you post the full method and annotations?

Comment: @Ernest Kiwele : You are right. I just tried given().log().all() and I could see the body being passed correctly.  I am sorry it was my bad that I had declared the map at 2 places (at class level and method level), which is why it was passing the body as blank when I tried given().log().all().

Comment: I am all set with this. I was able to see the correct body being passed using  given().log().all(). Sorry for the confusion

Comment: To avoid compilation error, use Arrays.asList(...) first.

Comment: Create a separate POJO class for 'Versions' with fields 'number' and 'attribute' and here you create a List<Versions> vList with values then put it in the map. Finally you download 'org.json' jar to format it in the way want like (new JSONObject(map)).

Comment: Thanks MAC. One question I had though, if I have multiple versions, how can I send that in the body? Say for example my request body is as below: The above code for using hashmap is not working. Can you please advise ?
{
    "name": "testmodel",
    "id": 27,
    "versions": [{
        "number": 1,
        "attribute": "test"
    }
 {
        "number": 2,
        "attribute": "test2"
    }
 
 ]
}